# ServiceStack.Text serialization exception (Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Void set_Item(Int32, MyApp.MyClass)')

Tags: c#, exception, serialization, deserialization, servicestack

I am trying to deserialize an object that contains nested lists of classes with ServiceStack.Text.

The serialization went well, but when trying to deserialize, I get this error:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1' threw an exception. --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1' threw an exception. --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeList`2' threw an exception. --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1' threw an exception. --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1' threw an exception. --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeList`2' threw an exception. --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1' threw an exception. --->
>   System.ArgumentException: Incorrect number of arguments supplied for
>   call to method 'Void set_Item(Int32, MyApp.MyClass)'

I have no method named set_Item in my solution, neither can I find a method named like this in the ServiceStack.Text assembly (using reflector). I have no clue of what the problem could be...And I need a fast serialization type, but the fastest I know(protobuf-net) doesn't support nested lists.

Any ideas? The class that caused the problem is below (the protomembers are there because I tested the protobuf method)

---

```
    [Serializable]
/// <summary>
/// Description of Livres.
/// </summary>
public class Livres : IEnumerable<Livre>
{

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    private List<Livre> listeLivres;

    public List<Livre> ListeLivres
    {
        get { return listeLivres; }
        set { listeLivres = value; }
    }

    public List<string> NomLivres 
    { 
        get
        {
            List<string> lst = new List<string>();
            foreach (Livre livre in this.listeLivres) 
            {
                lst.Add(livre.NomLivre);
            }
            return lst;
        }
    }

    public int Count 
    {
        get
        {
            return ((this.listeLivres != null) ? this.listeLivres.Count : 0);
        }
    }


    public Livre this[string nomLivre]
    {
        get
        {
            nomLivre = nomLivre.ToLower();
            if (nomLivre == "") 
            {
                return null;
            }
            try 
            {
                var u = this.listeLivres.Single(book => book.NomLivre.ToLower() == nomLivre);
                return u;
            } 
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                string pattern = "^[0-9][a-zA-Z]+$";
                Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
                if (reg.IsMatch(nomLivre)) 
                {
                    string nom = nomLivre[0].ToString() + " ";
                    nom += nomLivre.Substring(1).ToLower();
                    try 
                    {
                        var u = this.listeLivres.Single(book => book.NomLivre.ToLower() == nom);
                        return u;
                    } 
                    catch (Exception) 
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                else
                    return null;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if (nomLivre == "") 
            {
                throw new
                    ArgumentNullException("L'index ne doit pas être une chaine vide.");
            }
            try 
            {
                Livre liv = this.listeLivres.Single(book => book.NomLivre == nomLivre);
                liv = value;
            } 
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                string pattern = "^[0-9][a-zA-Z]+$";
                Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
                if (reg.IsMatch(nomLivre)) 
                {
                    string nom = nomLivre[0].ToString() + " ";
                    nom += nomLivre.Substring(1);
                    try 
                    {
                        Livre L = this.listeLivres.Single(book => book.NomLivre == nom);
                        L = value;
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException("Ce nom de livre n'existe pas dans la liste", e);
                    }
                }
                else
                    throw new ArgumentException("Ce nom de livre n'existe pas dans la liste", ex);
            }
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Obtient ou définit le Livre à l'index spécifié - 1
    /// Exceptions:
    /// ArgumentOutOfRangeException
    /// </summary>
    public Livre this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index < 1 || index > this.listeLivres.Count)
            {
                throw new
                    ArgumentOutOfRangeException("L'index spécifié n'était pas correct");
            }
            return this.listeLivres[index-1];

        }
        set
        {
            if (index < 1 || index > this.listeLivres.Count)
            {
                throw new
                    ArgumentOutOfRangeException("L'index spécifié n'était pas correct");
            }
            this.listeLivres[index - 1] = value;
        }
    }

    #region Constructeurs
    public Livres()
    {
        this.listeLivres = new List<Livre>();
    }
    public Livres(Livre livre)
        : this()
    {
        this.listeLivres.Add(livre);
    }

    #endregion  
    /// <summary>
    /// Retourne le verset correspondant si il existe, sinon null
    /// Exceptions
    /// ArgumentException
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="referenceComplete">La référence du verset sous forme de chaine (ex: "1 Jean 5:19")</param>
    public Verset GetVerset(string referenceComplete)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(referenceComplete))
            return null;
        string[] tab = referenceComplete.Split();
        try 
        {
            string livre = "";
            int chapitre;
            int verset;
            if (tab.Length>2) 
            {
                livre = tab[0];
            }
            livre += tab[tab.Length -2];
            string [] tabVerse = tab[tab.Length -1].Split(':');
            chapitre = Convert.ToInt32(tabVerse[0]);
            verset = Convert.ToInt32(tabVerse[1]);
            return this[livre][chapitre][verset];
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Il n'y a aucun verset avec cette référence",ex);
        }
    }

    public void Add(Livre livre)
    {
        this.listeLivres.Add(livre);
    }

    public static Livres operator +(Livres livres, Livre livre)
    {
        livres.Add(livre);
        return livres;
    }

    public IEnumerator<Livre> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (Livre item in this.listeLivres)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }


    public void Serialize(string pathName= "BibleData.txt")
    {
        try 
        {
            #region ServiceStack Serializer
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(pathName);
            TypeSerializer<Livres> TypeSrlzr = new TypeSerializer<Livres>();
            TypeSrlzr.SerializeToWriter(this,tw);
            //TypeSerializer.SerializeToWriter(this,tw);
            tw.Close();
            #endregion

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

    public static Livres Deserialize(string pathName= "BibleData.txt")
    {
        try
        {
            Livres Bible;
            #region ServiceStack Deserializer
            TextReader tr = new StreamReader(pathName);

            TypeSerializer<Livres> typeSrlzr = new TypeSerializer<Livres>();
            Bible = typeSrlzr.DeserializeFromReader(tr);
            //Bible = TypeSerializer<Livres>.DeserializeFromReader(tr);
            #endregion


            return Bible;
        } 
        catch (Exception) {

            throw;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the class you're trying to deserialize that's causing the error?

Comment: I've only had a chance to look at this today, unfortunately the code doesn't complile as it has missing a few classes. The JsonSerializer doesn't support cyclical dependencies which could be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to inherit from an IEnumerable as it will not likely behave in the way you expect. i.e. all Enumerables are serialized like a JSON Array/Collection and the additional properties are ignored.

The problem with only having an IEnumerable interface is that there is no way to generically populate it. So whilst you may be able to serialize it, you won't be able to deserialize it.

You would be more successful if you implemented a collection interface that also provides an ability to populate it, i.e. **IList<T>** or **ICollection<T>**.

Comment: I had all my classes that implemented IEnumerable implement IList, completed the need functions, and the problem remains the same

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I needed my classes to inherit IDataErrorInfo, and the problem is in the **indexed property**. You can fix it yourself in the source code though. In the OrmLiteConfigExtensions find the method GetModelDefinition and look for:

GetValueFn = propertyInfo.GetPropertyGetterFn(),
SetValueFn = propertyInfo.GetPropertySetterFn(),

replace the GetValueFn line only with:

GetValueFn = (propertyInfo.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)?null:propertyInfo.GetPropertyGetterFn(),

This way it will skip setting the GetValueFn property for indexed properties which throws the exception.